# Recover corrupted blocks in Oracle 10g XE

Tags: oracle, recovery, corruption, oracle-xe

I am using Oracle 10g XE. I've noticed corrupted block error in datafile 1 in alert log. As I've found Oracle XE doesn't support Block Media Recovery(needs to be Enterprise Edition).

So I did the following:

```
shutdown immediate;
startup mount;
recover database;
alter database open;
```

But corrupted blocks are still there.

Should not have my recover command solved this problem? Why not?

**Edit**

I have restored before recover and now it works. So the following steps are working:

```
 shutdown immediate;
 startup mount;
 restore database;
 recover database;
 alter database open;
```

Does recover just looks for the SCN and if the SCN is current for the datafile then recovers nothing? Not even corrupted ones?

As I guess recovery is just to apply archive logs(or online logs) to catch up to the current SCN, but not correcting corruptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you discovered by yourself, `RECOVER` is just the process of applying logs .

Since corruption occurs at physical level, you must restore the affected datafiles from a backup taken BEFORE the corruption occurs. `RESTORE` rebuilds the physical attributes of the datafile, so, any physical corruption (eg. disk failure) will be fixed.